# How can I write and deploy a custom authentication package in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-authentication, local-security-authority

I am trying to implement a custom authentication package where I can pass only user name from the custom credential provider to custom Authentication package and the Authentication package should check if that user name exists in Sam database if yes it should let me login, I am kind of trying to achieve a password less authentication here. I found the functions that are needed to implement this authentication package in windows documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/authentication-functions) as I am new to development of windows I didn't get much understanding from them, I am looking for a sample code of Authentication package where I can debug that sample and gain some knowledge on how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a big topic. Provide some related documents you check and follow:

Without password required you need create your [customized Credential Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows#custom-credential-providers).

[Creating Custom Security Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/creating-custom-security-packages)

[Winlogon and Credential Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/winlogon-and-credential-providers)

Samples:

- [SAMPSSP](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/security/authentication/sampssp) - This sample demonstrates the implementation of a Windows NT
  Security Support Provider.
- [MSV1_0 SubAuthentication Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/security/authentication/msvsubauth) - Authentication of users in the SAM database.
  Pass-Thru authentication of users in trusted domains.

Comment: Hi Rita, I have already created a custom credential provider which doesn't ask for password and passes a username to authentication, how ever do you think a sub authentication package would suffice my need of implementing password less authentication? Cause I thought I need to Implement a custom authentication package cause as per my basic understanding sub authentication package is specifying extra layer of conditions for  authentication along with conditions specified in The MSV1_0 package which accepts accepts a user name and a hashed password.

Comment: @Mohit Were you able to implement? If so then is there a possibility to see the code?